# strange behavior when debugging angularjs directives with lexical scoping (closure) in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools, lexical-scope

This is my code with a simple directive called test:

```
var app =  angular.module("app",[]);

app.directive('test',function(){
   return {
      link(scope,el,attrs){
        var outerVar = 'im in the outer scope';

        var myFunc = function(){
           var someText = 'just to be able to put a breakpoint here';
        }

        myFunc();

      }
   }
});
```

I added breakpoint at var someText. Then I tried to get the value from the dev tools console by typing in outerVar in I'm getting "ReferenceError: outerVar is not defined".

But when I modify myFunc as

```
var myfuction(){
 console.log(outerVar);
};
```

I'm getting the value and even more I can output the value from outVar on the dev tools console but only the outVar but not the outer variable like scope, el, and attrs ... and again if I do the a console.log for the other variables I get the same results -- it works, but not in the dev tools console.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome Developer Tools displays and provides access to *local* and *global* variables in the "Sources" and "Console" tabs when it hits a breakpoint you set. It will also provide a view of and access to "Closure" variables when they're used in the scope of the function you set the breakpoint in. This is why you're seeing your outer variable when calling console.log() inside of your function.

Developer Tools doesn't provide you with access to any variables in an outer scope which aren't used in the scope local to where the breakpoint is set, however. In order to access such variables in "Console" and to review in "Sources", you can select scopes above that of your breakpoint in the "Call Stack" section of "Sources".

Below is a commented example discussing where variables are visible from breakpoints inside functions. It doesn't include any AngularJS code since the issue you're describing is not at all Angular specific.

```
// seen as "Global" from breakpoint inside of myFunc or anywhere else
var global = "global"; 

(function() {
  // seen as "Closure" from breakpoint inside of myFunc only if used there 
  var outer = "outer"; 

  function myFunc() {
    // seen as "Local" from breakpoint inside of myFunc
    var inner = 'inner'; 

    // uncomment to see "outer" in Dev Tools
    //outer;

    debugger;
  }      
  myFunc(); 
})( );
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AG8GhJMltwHxeYPMCVK4)

Comment: in safari it gives you the values of the outer scope

Comment: Right, and I'm sure that both have reasons for doing things the way they do, but you only asked about/pointed out the issue with Chrome Developer Tools. And you should be able to do whatever you need to in either environment.

Comment: The point is that in Chrome the _outer_ variable is optimized out in V8, so it is not accessible where you are trying to reach out to it.